# Is mysql_query thread-safe if I init one mysql connection per thread?

Tags: mysql, c, thread-safety

what I want to know is that is mysql_query or other mysql function in C api thread-safe with the following conditions:

1. using the libmysqlclient.so but not the libmysqlclient_r.so
2. in every thread, call mysql_init and mysql_real_connect within the protect of an global mutex to get one mysql connection every thread
3. call mysql_query or other mysql function without the protect of the global mutex using each thread's own mysql connection

is this thread-safe ?

well I think it is, and from what I have tested, it seems it is thread-safe.

but I just not sure. can anyone tell me?

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety is a complicated issue. In one of my (Python) projects, I use one MySQL connection and protect every single call with a lock. That works with multiple threads.